# Docker (node:8.15-alpine) + Chromium + Karma unit tests not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, chromium, alpine-linux, karma-webpack

I'm trying to run my frontend tests on Docker (node:8.15-alpine) using Chromium and Karma, however I'm getting lots of ChromeHeadless related errors.

These tests used to work but recently they suddenly stopped, so I'm guessing it's either related to a third-party dependency (apk?), or the local Docker install.

I've created a branch on the repo with an easy to run command which reproduces the issue. README.md here: 
https://github.com/olivercaine/react-redux-starter-kit-extended/tree/bug/cant-run-unit-tests-in-docker

Any help with this would be masively appreciated!

Thanks.

Expected Outcome:

```
[output of passed tests...]
Finished in 0.026 secs / 0.031 secs @ 19:53:44 GMT+1100 (AEDT)
SUMMARY:
✔ 46 tests completed
```

Actual Outcome:

```sh
13 02 2020 09:10:45.314:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start ChromeHeadless

13 02 2020 09:10:45.316:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stdout:
13 02 2020 09:10:45.317:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stderr:
13 02 2020 09:10:45.772:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start ChromeHeadless

13 02 2020 09:10:45.772:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stdout:
13 02 2020 09:10:45.773:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stderr:
13 02 2020 09:10:45.939:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start ChromeHeadless

13 02 2020 09:10:45.939:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stdout:
13 02 2020 09:10:45.939:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stderr:
13 02 2020 09:10:46.424:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.

Finished in 0 secs / 0 secs @ 09:10:46 GMT+0000 (UTC)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-redux-starter-kit@3.0.1 test: `cross-env NODE_ENV=test karma start build/karma.config`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-redux-starter-kit@3.0.1 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-13T09_10_46_935Z-debug.log
```

Update:

The above URL has been removed, however the full (now working) repo can be found here:

https://github.com/olivercaine/react-redux-starter-kit-extended/tree/modpack/latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are some issues regarding the **node:8-alpine** image that you are using. See https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/379. I don't know if it's the same issue but I was able to run your tests using the **node:8.15-slim** as the base image of your base Dockerfile

You'll need to update your dev Dockerfile as well:

```
FROM olliecaine/base:master

WORKDIR /project

# Install Chrome
RUN apt update && apt install -y chromium
```

Ideally you would add **ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium** to this Dockerfile, but for some reason this is not setting the variable properly.

To check that yourself, and insert `console.log(process.env.CHROME_BIN)` at the beginning of your **build/karma.config.js** file, you will see the value is still /usr/bin/chromium-browser when running the tests.

As a workaround, I had to insert this line at the beginning of the **build/karma.config.js** file:

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = '/usr/bin/chromium'
```

Let me know if you understand why the ENV instruction is not working, I'm interested.

Comment: Yeah you're totally right.. how strange! I'm going to experiment with the apk side of things to see if I can find the proper fix. In the mean time though yours has unblocked me... cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Baptiste, your answer helped me verify the fix was working.
Basically what I ended up doing was using a different URL for alpinelinux.org.

In the end I changed the Dockerfile to:

```
FROM node:8.15-alpine

WORKDIR /project

# Install Chrome
RUN echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk --no-cache update && apk --no-cache upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache chromium \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /tmp/*

ENV CHROME_BIN /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

which seemed to set the CHROME_BIN env variable properly, allowing me to run my tests in the Alpine container. Also meant I didn't need to update the karma.config.js file either. Previously I was using **nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/** instead of **edge**.

Cheers for your help!