# How to install chromium in alpine docker to use html.render() from requests_html?

Tags: javascript, python, docker, alpine-linux, python-requests-html

I need to scrape a website that is js rendered. I found this nice working library requests_html that does the job. After using 'pip install requests_html' the following code will get the job done:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = examplesite

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=1)
print(r.html.html)
```

The first time that it runs it will install chromium in order to render the url. However, when I try to use this code in an alpine dockerfile I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.local/share/pyppeteer/local-chromium/588429/chrome-linux/chrome': '/root/.local/share/pyppeteer/local-chromium/588429/chrome-linux/chrome'
```

This is probably the case because the root folder is not present in the dockerfile. So how do I install chromium in a docker container? Also, I am not limited to this library, so if there are better ones to use that can work in a docker container, please let me know.

I already tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.13

RUN apk add --no-cache  chromium --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using a different container:

```
FROM python:3.8.13-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still use `alipne` Docker image without any error, add these lines to your Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.13

RUN apk add --no-cache chromium
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

To avoid `FileNotFoundError` on the `alpine` version, manual selection of the `chromium-browser` is required for the `Puppeteer`.

This is similar node.js example: [Docker (node:8.15-alpine) + Chromium + Karma unit tests not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60204785/docker-node8-15-alpine-chromium-karma-unit-tests-not-working)